# What't the relationship between subexp and polynomial kenrel?

Tags: parameterized-complexity

In parameterized algorithms, we know there is a problem that

1. has a subexponential parameterized algorithm (subexp for short) and a polynomial kernel (e.g., split edge deletion problem);
2. has no subexp, but has a polynomial kernel (e.g., paw-free edge deletion);
3. has no subexp and no polynomial kernel (e.g., $P_5$-free edge deletion).

So, **is there an example that has subexp but has no polynomial kernel?** (Now I consider a problem that has subexp, but I am not sure whether it admits a polynomial kernel.)
Or maybe some good references are talking about the relationship?

Comment: It is easy to create artificial examples by padding, e.g. the problem of finding a path of length $\sqrt{k}$ parameterized by $k$. I'll think about a natural example.

Comment: @Laakeri Ok, thanks.